# Extract only 1 message from all senders

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am building a messaging system and need to extract only the last message from each sender to a specified recipient. So, if 3 people each sent 5  messages(total of15 messages) to the recipient, I need to get 3 entries; the last message from each sender.

Here is my current SQL:

```
SELECT  
                        messages.*, 
                        user_accounts.uacc_id,
                        user_accounts.uacc_username,
                        user_profiles.upro_image_name
                    FROM messages
                        LEFT JOIN user_accounts 
                            ON messages.msg_from_uacc_fk = user_accounts.uacc_id
                        LEFT JOIN user_profiles 
                            ON user_profiles.upro_uacc_fk = user_accounts.uacc_id
                    WHERE 
                        messages.msg_to_uacc_fk = ?
                    ORDER BY 
                        msg_id
                    DESC
```

I tried adding 'MAX(1)' to the SELECT as well as 'LIMIT = 1' to after the DESC, but, of course, this just returned a total of 1 message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not simply use a group by?

```
SELECT u.uacc_username, max(m.msg_id) as LatestMsg
FROM messages m JOIN user_accounts u on m.msg_from_uacc_fk = u.uacc_id
WHERE m.msg_to_uacc_fk = ?
GROUP BY u.uacc_username
```

Comment: Hello, That almost works. It does now only get one message. However, it does not get last message. Should I be doing something with LatestMsg?

Answer (score 2):

It is sometimes hard to guess how the tables are designed but this query below uses a subquery to get the latest message for each user.

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        c.uacc_id,
        c.uacc_username,
        d.upro_image_name
FROM    messages a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  msg_from_uacc_fk, MAX(msg_id) max_id
            FROM    messages 
            GROUP   BY msg_from_uacc_fk
        ) b ON  a.msg_from_uacc_fk = b.msg_from_uacc_fk AND
                a.msg_id = b.max_id
        INNER JOIN user_accounts c
            ON  a.msg_from_uacc_fk = c.uacc_id
        INNER JOIN user_profiles d
            ON d.upro_uacc_fk = c.uacc_id
WHERE   a.msg_to_uacc_fk = ?
```

*If this doesn't solve the problem, please add sample records along with your question `:)`*

Comment: Thanks JW. Thanks toJohn Bingham's answer, I was just testing a solution that was almost identical to this.

Comment: Oh, BTW, the solution did work after seeing a difference in yours. Sorry I can't accept 2 answers.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, the answer John gave was 50% correct and guided me toward a solution that was almost identical to yours. So I figured he was entitled to the vote. It can be difficult sometimes to know whose answer to vote for when more than one person gives input that leads to a working solution.

Comment: What happened to JW's message I responded to? Now my message looks strange sitting there.